Why google app password doesn't let me login
I am trying to send some email using Google app password that I generated from my google account and the following code :
const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
  pool: true,
  host: 'smtp.gmail.com',
  priority: 'high',
  from: {
    name: 'my name',
    address: 'info@mydomain.com'
  },
  port: 587,
  secure: false,
  auth: {
    user: "info@mydomain.com",
    pass: "kbpzbvrkrrqvjwfb", // also tried with spaces
  },
  tls: {
    rejectUnauthorized: false
  }
});

Which I run into :
Error: Invalid login: 535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. For more information, go to
535 5.7.8  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials 2adb3069b0e04-521f38d7f71sm2899713e87.194 - gsmtp

Everything had been working for the past 6 months but suddenly today I can not longer access it. I did generate a new key which didn't change anything.
How can I overcome this issue?
